# There is no way to use variable using range

Tags: function, loops, go, scope, closures

I have written a simple script that will read the /proc/cpuinfo and return a `[]map[string]string` containing the info about the cores.

The problem is I am unable to use the values inside the range it always gives me the info of the last CPU.

I tried using closures literally everywhere with no success. And also I tried to copy the variables locally in the loop and still no success.

Here is my code

```
func GetCpuInfo() CpuInfo {
    cpus, err := os.Open("/proc/cpuinfo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Cannot open /proc/cpuinfo")
    }
    defer cpus.Close()
    s := bufio.NewScanner(cpus)
    cpuCores := make(CpuCores, 0)
    core := map[string]string{}
    for s.Scan() {
        txt := s.Text()
//copying the variable also does not work
        core := core

        if len(txt) == 0 {
//tried to use closure here with no success
            cpuCores = append(cpuCores, core)
            continue
        }
        fields := strings.Split(txt, ":")
        if len(fields) < 2 {
            continue
        }
//using closure here wont work either
        var k, v = strings.TrimSpace(fields[0]), strings.TrimSpace(fields[1])
        core[k] = v
    }
    return CpuInfo{
        Cores:    cpuCores,
        CpuCount: uint(runtime.NumCPU()),
        Brand:    cpuCores[0]["vendor_id"],
        Model:    cpuCores[0]["model name"],
    }
}
```

As you see from the code seems like there is no way to use this variable or i am really missing some huge point.

Comment: Why do you have the core map and the list?  It seems like you only append to cpuCores when txt == 0 and otherwise put things in the core map but in your return value you only use cpuCores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the way around by resetting the core variable after appending it

```
if len(txt) == 0 {
                cpuCores = append(cpuCores, core)
                core=map[string]string{}
            }
```

like this but I am not sure if this can cause a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to do something like:

```
struct CpuCore {
    VendorID string
    ModelName string
}

func GetCpuInfo() CpuInfo {
    cpus, err := os.Open("/proc/cpuinfo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Cannot open /proc/cpuinfo")
    }
    defer cpus.Close()
    s := bufio.NewScanner(cpus)
    cpuCores := make(CpuCore, 0)
    for s.Scan() {
        txt := s.Text()

        fields := strings.Split(txt, ":")

        if len(fields) < 2 {
            continue
        }

        var k, v = strings.TrimSpace(fields[0]), strings.TrimSpace(fields[1])
        cpuCores = append(cpuCores, CpuCores{VendorID: k, ModelName: v})
    }
    return CpuInfo{
        Cores:    cpuCores,
        CpuCount: uint(runtime.NumCPU()),
        Brand:    cpuCores[0].VendorID,
        Model:    cpuCores[0].ModelName,
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you have a struct `CpuCore` and that you want to make an array of them called `cpuCores`.

Perhaps if you include more of your code and types that would allow us to actually try to run this code.

Comment: actually cpu core is a map containint all the data about a single core /proc/cpuinfo provides and in my machine there are 4 cores so i wanna end up with a slice of maps of size 4 i get 4 entries but the problem is that they are the last cpu info only

Comment: Ah.  So you need to instantiate a new map every time through your loop.  Instead of creating `core` outside of the loop create it in the loop and you should be fine.  Right now you're making a list that contains four references to the exact same map which you keep overwriting with the last value.

Comment: That said, I think it is more idiomatic in go to use a Struct for this.

Comment: i cannot create because in every iteration theres something new added into the map and yes struct could be cooler but im reading from /proc/cpuinfo and i dont want to write a struct and manually assign all variables i get from cpuinfo file thats the reason i use map

Comment: what do u think will my approach below cause memory leak actually i think gc will deal with the trash info

Answer (score -1):

`//copying the variable also does not work
        core := core`

In golang, map types are reference types and we can not copy a map by `:=`.

You should make a new map in every loop.